# Show children of direct parent without specifying parent id

Tags: wordpress

In a Wordpress page I want to show children of the direct parent without wanting to specify the page

```
<?php
$pages = get_pages('child_of=143');
if ($pages) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($page->ID).'">';
        echo get_the_title($page->ID);
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID);
        echo '</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
?>
```

how can I grab the direct parent

Cheers for any help

Answer (score 1):

You can get the parent id through the following:

```
$post->parent_post
```

So, you could do something like:

```
$parent_id = $post->parent_post;
$pages = get_pages('child_of=' . $parent_id);
if ($pages) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $pages = get_pages('child_of='.get_query_var('page_id'));
    if ($pages) {
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($pages as $page) {
            echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($page->ID).'">';
            echo get_the_title($page->ID);
            echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID);
            echo '</a></li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
?>
```